# Помощь в Python

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста.
`f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ:'`
`f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x}'`
Мне нужно чтобы вместо {0}, ставился класс, в зависимости от значения.
Если 24, то класс `Real time class`.
Если 12, то класс `High class`.
Как это можно сделать?
При запуске мы добавляем значения через команды add1 24 затем add2 13. и запускаем через команду start. И в этой строке мы получаем что  f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n' вместо {x} ставится 24. А мне нужно чтобы кроме этого еще на месте, где стоит {0} ставился нужный класс. При значении {x} 24 это будет класс Real time class, если {x} 13, то Hight class и так далее
{x} берется из

```
idx = {} 
    
for x in idx:
        
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- config: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import queue
import threading
import time


class QueueThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self) -> None:
        print(f'Старт потока {self.name}')
        process_queue()
        print(f'Завершение потока {self.name}')


def process_queue():
    while True:
        try:
            x = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process1 = idx[x]
            y = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process2 = idx2[y]
        except queue.Empty:
            return
        else:
            print_factors(x, y, process1, process2, res_list)

        time.sleep(1)


def print_factors(x, y, process1, process2, res_list):
    try:
        for g in results:
            res_list = g[x]
    except KeyError:
        res_list = []
    current_res = []
    st = time.time()
    try:
        begin = drop_list[x]
    except KeyError:
        begin = 1
    for i in range(begin, x + 1):
        current = time.time()
        if i == x:
            del idx[x]

            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ:\n '
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ГОТОВНОСТЬ, в потоке \n'
                             f'появился процесс PID:2 с более высоким приоритетом: \n \n'
                             f'Значение приоритета процесса PID:1 = {x} \n'
                             f'Значение приоритета процесса PID:2 = {y} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ: \n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {y} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:2 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние ОЖИДАНИЕ \n '
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {y} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ \n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n'
                             f'Процесс PID:1 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние ОЖИДАНИЕ \n '
                             f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            break


def entry_get(event):
    global idx, cm_list, ps_queue
    command = en1.get()
    term.insert(END, f'# {command} \n')
    cm_list.append(command)
    en1.delete(0, 'end')
    if command == 'exit':
        root.destroy()
    elif command.startswith('add1 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command.startswith('add2 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx2[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command == 'clear':
        term.delete(0.0, END)
    elif command == 'start':
        thread1 = QueueThread('A')
        thread1.start()
    elif command == 'list':
        term.insert(END, f'Список приоритетов, состовляющих алгоритм планирования \n')
        for i in idx:
            term.insert(END, f'{i} \n')
        for i in idx2:
            term.insert(END, f'{i} \n')
    elif command == 'help':
        term.insert(END, f'"add1 УРОВЕНЬ ПРИОРИТЕТА" - добавляет уровень приоритета процесса 1.')
        term.insert(END, f'"add2 УРОВЕНЬ ПРИОРИТЕТА" - добавляет уровень приоритета процесса 2.')
        term.insert(END, f'"list" - выводит список приоритетов, для алгоритма планирования. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"clear" - очищает терминал. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"help" - выводит список команд. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"start" - запускает алгоритм планирования. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"exit" - выход. \n')
    else:
        term.insert(END, f'{command} -- неизвестная комманда, используйте "help". \n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    idx = {}
    idx2 = {}
    res_list = []
    results = []
    drop_list = {}
    cm_list = []
    ps_queue = queue.Queue()
    for x in idx:
        ps_queue.put(x)
    for y in idx2:
        ps_queue.put(y)
    r = str('Real time class')
    h = str('High class')
    a = str('Above normal class')
    n = str('Normal class')
    b = str('Below normal class')
    i = str('Idle class')
    info = str('неопределен')

    if idx == 24:
        print(r)
    elif idx == 13:
        print(h)
    elif idx == 10:
        print(a)
    elif idx == 8:
        print(n)
    elif idx == 6:
        print(b)
    elif idx == 4:
        print(i)
    if idx2 == 24:
        print(r)
    elif idx2 == 13:
        print(h)
    elif idx2 == 10:
        print(a)
    elif idx2 == 8:
        print(n)
    elif idx2 == 6:
        print(b)
    elif idx2 == 4:
        print(i)

    root = Tk()

    root.geometry('570x400')
    root.title("Подсистема управления процессами с алгоритмом планирования на основе абсолютных приоритетов")
    root.resizable(False, False)

    lb1 = Label(text='Командная строка:', width=0)
    lb2 = Label(text='Терминал:', width=0)
    en1 = Entry(width=68, bg='black', fg='white')
    term = Text(bg='black', width=65, height=19, fg='white')

    en1.bind('<Return>', entry_get)
    en1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: print(idx))

    lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=5)
    lb2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    en1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
    term.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: через output у меня сделать не получилось, скорее всего я что то делал неправильно. Прикрепил более полные фрагменты кода, посмотрите пожалуйста так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не совсем понятна, но можете взять что-то из такого кода:

```
class_info = {
    24: 'Real time class',
    13: 'High class',
    10: 'Above normal class',
    8: 'Normal class',
    6: 'Below normal class',
    4: 'Idle class'
}

idx = 10
x = 42
class_str = class_info.get(idx, 'неопределен')

print(f'Класс приоритета: {class_str}, значение - {x} \n \n')
```

Т.е. можно обойтись без множества `if` просто словарём, и инфу по классу точно так же через `f-string` подставлять из переменной в строку.

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял проблему, но вроде сделал:

```
idx = 1
output = 'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ: ' \
         'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - '
if idx == 1:
    output = output.format('Real time class')
    print(output)
```

Краткое пояснение: Мы бросаем текст в переменную, на место знаков вопроса ставим `{0}` - это ключ, по которому будет проходиться `output.format` и заменять на то, что передано в функцию. Объяснил как смог, если что-то осталось непонятным, спрашивайте!

Comment: Добавил полный фрагменты кода. посмотрите пожалуйста теперь. Через output у меня не получилось сделать, возможно я делал что то неправильно

Comment: Так, тогда объясните пожалуйста поподробнее, что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: У меня получилось прикрепить весь код программы. При запуске мы добавляем значения через команду add1 24 и add2 13. и запускаем через команду start. И в этой строке мы получаем что  f'Класс приоритета: {0}, значение - {x} \n \n' вместо {x} ставится 24. А мне нужно чтобы кроме этого еще на месте, где стоит {0} ставился нужный класс. При значении {x} 24 это будет класс Real time class, если {x} 13, то Hight class и так далее